# Controller file in openerp 6..?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

For days i've already about openerp structure, i understand it, openerp is mvc. From the tutorial :

Model : Postgre table

View  : XML file

Controller  : The objects of OpenERP

that make me still confuse is, when i'm trying to file where is controller file, i found a file inside the module (sale) , sale.py, i think it is the controller, but when i check inside the file, there is also a query inside there..

...

```
def _picked_rate(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    if not ids:
        return {}
    res = {}
    for id in ids:
        res[id] = [0.0, 0.0]
    cr.execute('''SELECT
            p.sale_id, sum(m.product_qty), mp.state as mp_state
        FROM
            stock_move m
        LEFT JOIN
            stock_picking p on (p.id=m.picking_id)
        LEFT JOIN
            procurement_order mp on (mp.move_id=m.id)
        WHERE
            p.sale_id IN %s GROUP BY mp.state, p.sale_id''', (tuple(ids),))
```

...

As I know from other framework, about model, view and controller are separated in different file(CI, Yii, etc). So what about openerp? What about the controller and the model?

Answer (score 2):

The MVC architecture description in the [Developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/02_architecture.html#mvc-architecture) tell you that "In OpenERP, we can apply this model-view-controller semantic with":

- model : The PostgreSQL tables.
- view : views are defined in XML files in OpenERP.
- controller : The objects of OpenERP.

`sale.py` defined the objects and business logic, so it's the controller. However, sometimes the implementation code bypasses the ORM and accesses the database directly, running SQL through the `execute()` method. This ought to be the exception, since the proper way would be through the ORM's [`browse()`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/02_architecture.html#mvcsql) method.

Also note that, although the model components "hosted" by PostgreSQL tables, in fact they are defined in the `.py` files. I would say the the `.py` files define both the model and the controller logic.

Comment: so it means model and controller is in same file, isn't it? so what about *.mako file? what the difference between *.py and *.mako in openerp?

Comment: .mako file is created to generate webkit reports while .py file is used to define model & business logic.

Answer (score 1):

OpenERP can be applied to The Standard MVC, but OpenERP is a [multitenant](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/02_architecture.html#technical-architecture), three-tier architecture. as per the framework model can be access through the controller eg.

```
cr.execute('select partner_id from sale_order where id=%d', (ID,))
partner_id = cr.fetchone()[0]
```

by overriding fields_view_get method one can also create view from the controller(.py file)([Doc](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html))